# How to run aws cli comands in python using subprocess module

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, boto3, aws-cli

I am trying to run a very basic AWS CLI command from python, instead of using boto3

So I found one answer from stack overflow I tried that but it didn't do any better, I don't want to use boto3, below is my code which I have tried

```
import subprocess

cmd='aws s3 ls'
push=subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
print push.returncode
```

If I run these commands into bash scripts it works perfectly fine. But I have a restriction that it has to be done using python scripts only.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask _why_ you wish to run the AWS CLI from Python?

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation for [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode) states, `.returncode` stores the child process return code. After running your code I am seeing this output:

```
ania@blabla:~$ python3 test.py 
None
ania@blabla:~$ 
[Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Checking again the aforementioned docs:

> A `None` value indicates that the process hasn’t terminated yet.

So let's modify your code to wait for the child process to end (I am using Python 3):

```
import subprocess

cmd='aws s3 ls'
push=subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
push.wait()   # the new line
print(push.returncode)
```

Now, in the output I get the exit status 0:

```
ania@blabla:~$ python3 test.py 
0
```

This is advice about an issue with the `subprocess` module, but what bothers me is why you don't want to use the `boto3` module which is specifically written for sending API calls to AWS from Python. I discourage you from using `subprocess` to send these requests and switch to `boto3`, if possible.

Comment: Actually i am trying to run some things which i know how to do with aws cli commands but not with python so i just want to learn any way to run cli commands in pythons just because of that i put the simple command of aws s3 ls

Comment: Alright, I hope my answer was helpful then. If it solved your problem, you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try following commands.

```
import subprocess

push=subprocess.call(['aws', 's3', 'ls', '--recursive', '--human-readable', '--summarize'])
```

or

```
import subprocess

push=subprocess.run(['aws', 's3', 'ls', '--recursive', '--human-readable', '--summarize'])
```

Wish help for you.